# How to evaluate Expression inside Expression in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to evaluate an expression inside expression using angularJS.Please let me know how to do it?

Problem:

I have two objects department and facility and i want to display departments and facilities in accordions. So, i am able to pass department object and facility object. Now the problem arises.As the department object has property department_name and facility has facility_name.I passed the department_name and 
facility_name to label attribute in directive and trying to use in accordion html like this {{item.{{label}}}}.I don't think this is right. But please let me know how can i do this.

Thanks in advance

In HTML:

```
 <accordion-directive object="department" label="department_name">
 </accordion-directive>
 <accordion-directive object="facility" label="facility_name">
</accordion-directive>
```

In Accordion HTML

```
 <accordion-group ng-repeat="item in object>
 <accordion-heading>
{{item.{{label}}}} // For departments it should be  department[0].department_name
                 // For Facility it should be facility[0].facility_name

 </accordion-heading>
</accordion-group>
```

JSON file:

```
    {
   "department": [
                   {
                     "department_name": "department 1", 
                   },
                  {
                   "department_name": "department 2",
                  } 
                 ]
        }

       {
    "facility": [
                   {
                    "facility_name": "Facility 1"
                   },
                   {
                    "facility_name": "Facility 2"
                   }
                ]
}
```

Directive:

```
          angular.module("app").directive('accordDirective', function () {
           return {
           restrict: 'E',
             scope: {
               object: '=',
               label:'@'
              },
             templateUrl: 'accordian.html',    
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use square brackets:

```
{{item[label]}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Micheal. But how is it working. Could you explain ? It would be really helpful for me.

Comment: That's javascript basic. You can access an object property as `object.foo` or `object ['foo']`. See [Property Access](http://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-object-syntax/) for more information.

Comment: Yeah, I got it yesterday only, just forgot the basics key[value] . Anyway thanks Michael .